# Upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 22 and install ROS 2 Humble

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am presently having Ubuntu 18 on my laptop with ROS Melodic installed and I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 22 and install ROS 2 Humble. I want to know if upgrading to higher Ubuntu versions causes any problems in the existing ROS codes and packages. I just want to upgrade my Ubuntu version, install ROS Noetic and install ROS 2 Humble. If anybody has upgraded their Ubuntu version, please let me know if you encountered any problems in running previous existing ROS Melodic or previous ROS version packages or it is safe to upgrade and all existing ROS packages run smoothly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410987/upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-to-ubuntu-22-and-install-ros-2-humble/) by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2022-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Noetic is the last ROS 1 distribution, and it is only supported in Ubuntu 20.04. You won't be able to use any ROS 1 packages in Ubuntu 22.04; you'll have to migrate your packages to ROS 2 Humble first. This is definitely not a trivial process, but here is a good place to start: [Migration Guide](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/The-ROS2-Project/Contributing/Migration-Guide.html)

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2022-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on 2022-12-31**:
Ok thank you for answering my question and thanks for providing the migration guide link. I have one more question, does ROS Noetic and ROS 2 Humble work on Ubuntu 20?

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2023-01-01**:
ROS Noetic works on Ubuntu 20.04. ROS 2 Humble only works on 22.04. ROS 2 Foxy and ROS 2 Galactic work on Ubuntu 20.04, but Galactic just went end-of-life on December 9th.

[ROS 1 Distros](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)

[ROS 2 Distros](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases.html)

**Comment by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on 2023-01-01**:
Ok got it, thank you for answering all my questions and providing the links for ROS 1 and ROS 2 version distributions.

**Comment by [Cervalls](https://answers.ros.org/users/163841/cervalls/) on 2023-07-19**:
Hello @Robo_guy,
Regarding this project, how did it evolve. I actually find myself in the same situation. I had a Ubuntu 18 with ROS Melodic and migrated my workspace to a Ubuntu 20.04 with Ros Noetic machine. Minor issues with Python 2 and Python 3 came up.
I am now looking to update to ROS 2 and am hesitating whether to go for:

1. Ubuntu 20.04+ROS2 Foxy(+ROS1 Noetic) - conservative approach with EoL in June 2023
   OR
2. Ubuntu 22.04+ROS2 Humble - bolder approach

**Comment by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on 2023-07-21**:
Hi @Cervalls, it depends, I needed to upgrade since the ROS2 version supported on melodic at reached EOL and the projects I am working on require ROS 1 Noetic and ROS2 Foxy. Regarding your decision, you should see if you are going to need ROS 1 or only ROS2. If you are going to need only ROS 2 then go with Ubuntu 22.04+ROS2 Humble but if your work will involve using both ROS 1 and ROS 2 then go for Ubuntu 20.04+ROS2 Foxy(+ROS1 Noetic)